# Postgres - split number and letter doesnt fill column

Tags: sql, postgresql, split

I have received help for splitting a column wit nr and letter. 
In the SQL script it all works perfect. It runs complete, with no errors.

But the columns itself doesn't get filled. 
I have tried to create te columns in advance as text or as integer. But it doesn't get filled. The SQL query it self turn out ok. But in reality it stay empty. What is wrong?

Comment: Running a `SELECT` statement won't insert values into the database

Comment: @aardvarkk do have some tips what is should be?

Comment: whats the table name on your pic to the right?..

Comment: I have a table with the name <hn> in there is for example 56 and 58A. In need to split this to 58 - in column nr. And A into zusatz (extension). So i need to select it all and insert into the new (or created by the script) columns. if it has no extension, like only 56, it must leave zusatz (extension) null/blanc

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not completely clear, but it sounds like what you are trying to do is take a value from one column of a table, split it and use the result to update two other columns in the same table.

If that is the case, you would want to be using the SQL [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html) command instead of SELECT.

```
UPDATE d1_plz_whatever
    SET nr=SUBSTRING(hn FROM '^[0-9]+'),
        zusatz =SUBSTRING(hn FROM '[a-zA-Z]+$');
```